# Horizontally scrolling by a full page on key press

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scroll, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an entirely horizontally spread page that one can scroll by pressing, for example, <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, and etc, to navigate.

I currently have two problems that I would like to solve:

1. When pressing <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> keys, the page is moved slightly more than 100vw, but the goal for it is to have perfectly aligned page edges with the window.
2. If for instance, you press the <kbd>Page Down</kbd> key multiple times when you reach the end of the page, it will take you the same number of <kbd>Page Up</kbd> presses to scroll back.

I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this.

Here is my code:

```js
let scrollAmount = 0
const container = document.documentElement

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeyup = event => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "Space":
      case "PageDown":
      case "ArrowRight": {
        scrollAmount += window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "PageUp":
      case "ArrowLeft": {
        scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "Home":
      case "ArrowUp": {
        scrollAmount = 0
        break
      }
      case "End":
      case "ArrowDown": {
        scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth
        break
      }
    }

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollAmount,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }
}

// Reset the scrollAmount if the user scrolls back manually.
window.onscroll = event => {
  scrollAmount = container.scrollLeft
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html, body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

body {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  overflow-x: auto
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 { color: white }
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `event.preventDefault()` and changing the listener to `keydown` instead of `keyup` will prevent the default continuous scrolling for the arrow keys. This works because the arrow key scrolling is triggered while it's held down (which we've now prevented), while the event listener was only being triggered when the arrow key is lifted.

You could do the same (add `event.preventDefault()`, that is) for <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> to prevent all horizontal scrolling.

```js
let scrollAmount = 0
const container = document.documentElement

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeydown = event => { // <-----------
    switch (event.code) {
      case "Space":
      case "PageDown":
      case "ArrowRight": {
        event.preventDefault(); // <-----------
        scrollAmount += window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "PageUp":
      case "ArrowLeft": {
        event.preventDefault(); // <-----------
        scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "Home":
      case "ArrowUp": {
        scrollAmount = 0
        break
      }
      case "End":
      case "ArrowDown": {
        scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth
        break
      }
    }

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollAmount,
    })
  }
}

// Reset the scrollAmount if the user scrolls back manually.
window.onscroll = event => {
  scrollAmount = container.scrollLeft
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html, body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

body {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  overflow-x: auto
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 { color: white }
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```